input pasar value a variable de checkbox personalizada
de nuevo con los desafíos de js en integración con html.
En este caso en hacer un calculo de honorarios, el cual se compone en base a un presupuesto, se van calculando los distintos aportes.
Esos aportes los debo agregar a mi carrito de compras el cual requiere una serie de valores para ser cargado. Los mismos están determinados en el checkbox.
A ver si con el Código me explico mas:
<td>Honorarios</td>
  <td>$
    <input name="honorarios" type="text" id="honorarios" value="" 
  onkeyup="calcular()"/></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Arancel Administrativo</td>
  <td>$
  <input name="arancel" type="text" id="arancel" value=""/></td>
  <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="select_product1" 
  value="" checked="checked" data-iddeuda="1" data-conc="Arancel Administrativo" data- 
  monto=""></label>
  </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Aportes 5% al CIEC</td>
  <td>$
    <input name="cinco" type="text" id="cinco" value=""/></td>
  <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="select_product1" 
  value="" checked="checked" data-iddeuda="2" data-conc="Aportes 5% al CIEC" data- 
  monto=""></label>
  </div></td>
  </tr>

Mi complicación es como rellenar la variable  data-monto="" con el valor que me calcula el scripts.
<script>
function calcular() {
var honorarios = 0;
var arancel = 12000.00;
var cinco = 0;
    
var monto = 0;
honorarios=eval(document.getElementById('honorarios').value);
if(honorarios <= 16400.00){
    tiv = 16400.00;
} else {
    tiv = honorarios * 0.05;    
}
document.getElementById('cinco').value=tiv.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('arancel').value=arancel.toFixed(2);
total = arancel + tiv;
document.getElementById('monto').value=total.toFixed(2);

};
</script>

Esto se puede hacer o tengo que usar otro método para tal fin?
Muchas Gracias por su Atención y ayuda.

Lo más básico: document.getElementById('id').setAttribute('foo', 'bar'); setearía el atributo data-foo al valor bar... Antes de preguntar es necesario investigar, y algo tan básico es muy fácil de encontrar en google...

Benito-B, gracias por querer ayudarme, lamentablemente no anda el codigo que me pasaste

Los atributos data-* son accesibles mediante la propiedad dataset
Por ejemplo, digamos que tenemos un elementos HTML con data-valor1 y data-valor2 y adicionalmente agregamos con javascript un tercer elemento data-valor3


//agregamos un nuevo data
elemento.dataset.valor3 = "C";

//leemos todos los data
for(let i in elemento.dataset){
   console.log("Nombre:" + i , "Valor:" + elemento.dataset[i]);
}
<div id="elemento" data-valor1="A" data-valor2="B"></div>




Para ponértelo en simple, en tu caso sería:
document.getElementById('cbox1').dataset = arancel.toFixed(2);


Tal como expuse en el comentario... para setear un atributo personalizado de un elemento basta con usar el método setAttribute, tal como indica la documentación propia de MSDN.
Obviamente tienes que identificar el elemento correctamente con su id o de la manera que quieras. En el comentario cometí un error indicando que al usar setAttribute('foo... se setearía data-foo, eso no es así. Se setea con el nombre exacto que le indicas en la función así que si quieres que se llame "data-monto" simplemente escribes setAttribute('data-monto', 'valor').


const element = document.getElementById('test');

element.setAttribute('foo', 'bar');

console.log('El atributo "foo" del elemento vale:', element.getAttribute('foo'));
<div id="test">
este es mi div
</div>



Incluso puedes verlo en el inspector del DOM:

Ahora solo te queda adaptar el código a lo que tú necesitas.
